# How to find vertice by two angles and side?

Tags: functions

I know 'alpha', 'betta', length 'c', coords: 'A' and 'B'
How can i find the 'C'(coords)?

[image]

Comment: `ASATriangle[α, c, β]`

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) may help.

Comment: Why was this topic moved from mathematica.stackexchange.com? This question is more suited over there.  Plus, rewi's answer is correct (given that $A=(0,0)$, $B=(c,0)$, and the $y$-coordinate of $C$ is positive).  For other choices of $A$ and $B$, you can implement a translation and a rotation manually, and probably also a reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume $A$ and $B$ are on the same ordinate for the sake of simplicity. Then

$$ b \cdot \sin \alpha = a \cdot \sin \beta = C_y - A_y $$
$$ a \cdot \cos \beta + b \cdot \cos \alpha = c $$

Once you have solved the system for $a$ or $b$ you can calculate $C$ coordinates ($C_x = A_x + a \cdot \cos \beta, C_y = A_y + a \cdot \sin \beta$)